# Remote Validation with Knockout in MVC 4, Allowing invalid data to save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation, remote-validation

Hi there I am using remote validation with knockout validation rules to check if a client is booked at the same time as the proposed date. I finally got the viewmodel sending data to the controller validation method and the method does return a true or false however i began to notice that the call back was not stopping the user from saving if the client is not valid.

I found this by swapping the conditions and allowing the controller method to return false I debugged the client side and found that the call back variable was in fact false but i was not receiving an error messae nor was it stopping m from saving the appointment.

My question is am i missing a piece of code that allows this or is there a bug that i am missing?

Viewmodel rule validation:

```
ko.validation.rules['validateClientasync'] = {
    async: true,
    message: 'Client is already booked in at this time!',
    validator: function (val, parms, callback) {
        var defaults = {
            url: '/Appointments/CheckClient/',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            success: function (data) {
                callback(/* true or false depending on what you get back in data */);
            }
        };


        if (parms.data != undefined && parms.data.appointment != undefined) {

            var appointment = ko.toJS(parms.data.appointment);


            $.ajax({
                url: '/Appointments/CheckClient/',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: ko.toJS(parms.data.appointment),
                success: function(data) {
                    callback(/* true or false depending on what you get back in data */);
                }
            });
        }


    }
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

self.appointment = {
    id: appointment.id,
    start: ko.observable(appointment.start),
    end: ko.observable(appointment.end),
    text: ko.observable(appointment.text),
    clientid: ko.observable(appointment.clientid).extend({
        validateClientasync: {
            data: self
        }
    }),
    employeeid: ko.observable(appointment.employeeid),
    roomid: ko.observable(appointment.roomid),
    fee: ko.observable(appointment.fee).extend({min: 10})
};
```

Comment: Where's the callback and does it actually return false if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

according to the definition in https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Async-Rules, just put a json there would be enough, like:

```
callback(
{ 
    isValid: true //true or false with json format returned from the validation method in your controller, 
    message: "your cusotm error message here" 
}
);
```